# why is my nav-tab is not working for bootstrap 4 with angular 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use tabs of bootstrap 4 with angular 4
I expected it to look and behave like this 
[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab&stacked=h)

But my page looks like this.
[image]

Below are my codes :

angular-cli.json:

```
"prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/cosmo/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
  ],
  "addons":[
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/font/*.+(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)"
  ],
  "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

main.componenet.html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tab">
    <li class="nav-item">  home <i class="fa fa-home"></i></li>
    <li class="nav-item">product</li>
</ul>
```

There's no error but still tabs are not seen. I am not sure why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this template

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">home
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks it worked so basically I need to add nav-link as well :)

Comment: Awsome!! Thanks!!!